# Problem with CiviCase

Tags: civicase, permissions

I have tried to enable the access to the Access my cases and activities as per The docs here - https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/case-management/set-up/

Access my cases and activities: allows a user to create new cases, add activities to the cases they've created and edit those activities. Users with this permission can NOT see cases or activities created by others.

However, whenever a user with that permission tries to access their own case they get an access denied. I think it has to do with the edit activities that are in cases. Has anyone else had this issue. It makes the "Access my cases and activities" permission unusable.

Using CiviCRM Version 5.3.2 and Drupal 7.59

Comment: New Problem? in Civi 5.6.1 - if you check "access my cases and activities" but do not have "Access ALL Cases and activities" when you go to access the Case dashboard or Manage Cases the account gets "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" And we can't give access to all Cases...?

Comment: Looks like you did some digging and found it's extension-related, so just posting the update for others looking: https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.civicase/issues/120

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a bug. It's coming from CRM_Case_Page_Tab::preProcess(), which calls CRM_Case_BAO_Case::getCases(), which then returns a list that's keyed sequentially, but then preProcess checks for a key that matches the case id, so there is no match.

```
$userCases = CRM_Case_BAO_Case::getCases(FALSE, array('type' => 'any'));
if (!array_key_exists($this->_id, $userCases)) {
  CRM_Core_Error::fatal(ts('You are not authorized to access this page.'));
}
```

This appears to have inadvertently been changed as part of [CRM-21461](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21461). I'll file a bug report.

Comment: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/297

Comment: Thanks @Demerit. Appreciate you taken the time to check this and identify it as a core bug.

Comment: If you want a quick hack, try changing line 679 in CRM/Case/BAO/Case.php from `foreach ($result->fetchAll() as $key => $case) {` to `foreach ($result->fetchAll() as $case) { $key = $case['case_id'];`, but I haven't tested for side effects.

Comment: Hi @Demerit. Thanks for the suggestion and raising the bug. Hopefully the core team can fix this soon.

Answer (score 3):

This was a regression which is now being fixed. See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12613

Comment: Thanks @Coleman - Is this available in the latest CiviCRM 5.4 release?

Comment: Looks like there was a delay in getting it merged so it will be in 5.6.

Comment: Thanks @Coleman & Demerit and the CiviCRM team for fixing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this patch https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.civicase/pull/123

Hope that helps!