# CiviCase Permissions

Tags: civicase

So I am very new to both civicrm and Drupal, but I have read the setup and can’t seem to get the permissions to work for Civicase

Obviously my administrator account - it all works. I created a second user ( and yes I made sure the user was in both civicrm and drupal ) I get access denied for my other user and really the only permission for civicase that is different is seeing only my cases is checked for the standard user, and all cases is unchecked - can someone give me a basic persmissions list to make this work.

Comment: You might want to check and see if the second user has permissions to access CiviCRM as well as permissions to access/view any case related entities (e.g. contacts, activities, custom data, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Problem with CiviCase](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25950/problem-with-civicase), which is scheduled to be fixed in version 5.6 as per the comments there.

Comment: Just as an Update i Followed the solution listed [Here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25950/problem-with-civicase) and the permissions are now working as they should