# "CiviCase: access all cases and activities" Issues

Tags: error, civicase

I realize that this has been spoken about and that there was a solution on posted (and it did work for me on 5.4 - Now on Civi 5.6.1 any user that does not have "CiviCase: access all cases and activities" checked i get a "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" error when trying to access the Civicase Dashboard or Manage Cases.

I checked if the fixes were applied from the pull - And Yes they are, but I cannot have users seeing other peoples Cases - 
It works for the Administrator - I can access all the Cases and don't get the redirect error.

Comment: is this  a potential duplicate of this question https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25950/problem-with-civicase which refers to this issue https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12613

Comment: ah i see you are on 5.6.1 - hmm

Comment: perhaps you could engage on that PR if you think the fix hasn't resolved everything

Comment: Looks like you did some digging and found it's extension-related, so just posting the update for others looking: https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.civicase/issues/120

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this patch https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.civicase/pull/123

Hope that helps!